# How to join two query in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: oracle9i

How can I join these queries?

```
SELECT RCTDT, SUM(RCTAMOUNT), COUNT(RCTAMOUNT) FROM RECEIPTS4
WHERE RCTDT BETWEEN '01-nov-2009' AND '30-nov-2009' 
AND RCTTYPE='CA' AND RCTAMOUNT>0
GROUP BY RCTDT

---

SELECT RCTDT, SUM(RCTAMOUNT), COUNT(RCTAMOUNT) FROM RECEIPTS4
WHERE RCTDT BETWEEN '01-nov-2009' AND '30-nov-2009' 
AND RCTTYPE='CQ' AND RCTAMOUNT>0
GROUP BY RCTDT
```

Comment: do u want to combine both query results into single row? or just want to merge the queries?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT RCTDT, SUM(RCTAMOUNT), COUNT(RCTAMOUNT) FROM RECEIPTS4
WHERE RCTDT BETWEEN '01-nov-2009' AND '30-nov-2009' 
AND RCTTYPE IN ('CA','CQ') AND RCTAMOUNT>0
GROUP BY RCTDT
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe  you meant this

```
SELECT RCTDT,
 SUM(case when rcttype='CA' then RCTAMOUNT else null end) as CASUM, 
 COUNT(case when rcttype='CA' then RCTAMOUNT else null end) as CACOUNT,
 SUM(case when rcttype='CQ' then RCTAMOUNT else null end) as CQSUM, 
 COUNT(case when rcttype='CQ' then RCTAMOUNT else null end) as CQCOUNT,
FROM RECEIPTS4
WHERE RCTDT BETWEEN '01-nov-2009' AND '30-nov-2009' 
AND RCTTYPE in('CA','CQ') AND RCTAMOUNT>0
GROUP BY RCTDT
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example, use an `IN` as suggested by cletus. In other cases, where the two result sets cannot be generated from the same select, use a `UNION` to combine the results:

```
SELECT something FROM somewhere
UNION
SELECT something FROM somewhere_else
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT RCTDT, SUM(RCTAMOUNT), COUNT(RCTAMOUNT) FROM RECEIPTS4
WHERE RCTDT BETWEEN '01-nov-2009' AND '30-nov-2009' 
AND RCTTYPE IN ('CA','CQ') AND RCTAMOUNT>0
GROUP BY RCTDT

can also be useful.